# Finding what interface a MAC address is assigned to

Tags: switch, network, cisco-commands

I am currently on a Cisco 9410 and I ran a "sh mac address-table | i 5619" and I received

" 13    fc3f.db4d.5619    DYNAMIC     Po1".

I just need assistance with finding what port/interface that this device is connected to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `|i(nclude) 5619` in your command filters the output to only display lines that contain `5619`. That way, you won't see the table headers with

```
          Mac Address Table
-------------------------------------------

Vlan    Mac Address       Type        Ports
----    -----------       --------    -----
```

and the interface in the rightmost column that you'd see without `|i`.

With a more complete regex implementation you could use `|i (5619|Vlan)` to enable the column header as well, but switches usually only support a subset.

Alternatively, you could just use `show mac address-table fc3f.db4d.5619` without filtering to show a headered table.

Comment: Looks like a bug

Comment: No bug. If you ask for output with only "5619" in them, the header - not containing that string - will not be displayed.

Comment: Yeah I know...it behaves like grep, but anyway would be nice to see the header

Answer (score 4):

That MAC address is assigned to `PortChannel1`. That is the `Po1` in the result you got.

Answer (score 2):

To find the actual physical interface where that MAC address was learned, issue the command 'sh interfaces port-channel 1' or if you want to see a smaller output, 'sh interfaces port-channel 1 etherchannel' or 'sh interfaces port-channel 1 | i Members'

That will tell you the ports that are members of the port-channel link aggregation group. You can trace any active/linked member port/cable because they have to go to a peer that is configured for participation in the port-channel, assuming things are setup correctly.